# Get the first of a list that gets iterated six times

Tags: python-3.x

I have list that contains six elements and the list gets iterated, and inside the list there is another list which contains only three elements but the problem is that, the three element list becomes six inside   the for loop of the other list.

```
    first = [1,0,3,0,5,0]

    sec = [2,4,6]


    for item in first:
    print(sec)

    """
   [2, 4, 6]
   [2, 4, 6]
   [2, 4, 6]
   [2, 4, 6]
   [2, 4, 6]
   [2, 4, 6]
   I want to get the first one only.
   expected output [2,4,6]
   """
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think  you only want [2,4,6] as output you don't want that list to get printed for 6 times
so to get only one  output (just first one) you can use **break** statement ,

```
for item in first:
    print(item)
    break
```

know more about break statement-https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm#:~:text=It%20terminates%20the%20current%20loop,both%20while%20and%20for%20loops.